# Adding custom subview in IB

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface-builder

I have two nib files: the main application window, and a small view that I want to use in it. How can I insert instance of this view into the main window using interface builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  If you want a small view in your main application window, just drag a custom view object onto your window in the main nib.

You can add your second nib view to your main window, but that has to be done in code.  The usual way to do that is to add a new file to your project that's a subclass of NSViewController -- you will get a new xib file with this that has a view.  Then you would alloc initWithNibName:bundle: to create an instance of your view controller, and add its view to your main window's contentView.

Comment: But how can I create a custom view object from the view I created in the first place?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. When you drag out a custom view, that is a view object.  Normally you would create a subclass of NSView and set the class of that custom view to your class. You can add any UI elements you want to the view, and hook them up in your subclass.

Comment: I thought that by 'custom object' in the first paragraph of your answer you meant an object stored in 'Custom Objects' partition of the library (which is empty by default), and I don't understand how do I put something there.

Comment: I don't see any custom objects section.  Are you in iOS or OSX?  Sorry, I found it -- no it's not in there, it's in the regular objects list

Comment: OSX. Object Library, Custom Objects — in the very end.

Comment: What I did now:

1) Created a subclass of NSViewController with associated nib file

2) Created all the logic of controller, wired it to nib file

3) Created a subclass of NSView

4) Set the view to be of this view class

5) In main nib file, created a custom view. Set this view to be of the same custom view too.

I expected this custom view to look like what I created in the nib file, but it's still just empty.

Comment: I think to put something in the custom objects section you have to create an interface builder plugin.

Comment: When you create a nib instance of your subclass, you have to load the instance of that subclass _from that nib_ in order to get the custom layout from it.  Otherwise you just create a subclass item without all the stuff you added.

Comment: I'm very gratefull for all that help, but I'm still confused. Once I dropped the custom view into the main window, I have an instance of a custom view. However, the init method you mentioned earlier is for view controller. I can alloc and init a new view controller, but how do I connect the two?

Comment: They should already be connected.  In IB, the File's Owner should be your new view controller, and its view property should be hooked up to your view.  In code, you just use vc.view to access the view (where vc is the property that you assigned your view controller to when you alloc init'd it).

Comment: I tried the following: alloc & init custom ViewController, and set it's view to the custom view I already have in the main view. It compiles OK, but I still see just blank space ;(

Comment: I'm a little lost now -- Where did your view come from?  Was it the one you got automatically when you added the view controller subclass file? Or, did you drag a custom view into your window in the main xib file? And, what do you have in your custom view? Is there anything to see?

Comment: I dragged empty custom view to the main window, declared it to be of my custom view class. Then in the initialization of the main window, I alloc & init the view controller, and now I have this two objects — view and view controller — completely independent. My custom view in the main window is empty, but it's nib is not.

Comment: I've never done it exactly this way, but I think you need an IBOutlet in whatever class your alloc init'ing your view controller class from, that you connect to your custom view in IB.  Then call setView: on your view controller instance, and pass it the outlet property that you created and hooked up

Comment: I've tried exactly that with no results. Can you please describe how you did it?

Comment: I don't think you can do it that way.  The instance of the custom view that you dragged won't have the custom stuff on it because it wasn't initialized with the nib.  I recommend creating the custom view on the main view and then creating a custom controller to tie it to.

Comment: @mydogisbox, how do I do that?

Comment: Maybe my original answer was not clear -- I meant that you could either drag a custom view into your main window and create a NSView subclass, OR, you could add a view controller subclass and add whatever you want to the view that's created for you in the new xib file.  You seem to be mixing the 2 approaches. I did it by adding the view controller class, and adding things to the view it provides. Then do the alloc initWithNibName:bundle, and add it to the window with self.window.contentView addSubview:vc.view

Comment: You're absolutely correct, this did the trick. Thanks for all the help!